# Unit testing a controller method fails because view is null

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm using Grails 2.2.0.
This is my method to be tested:

```
def extendedSearchIndex () {
    log.debug("ExtendedSearchIndex ... ");
    def deviceClass = deviceService.getDeviceClass(request)
    if (deviceClass == "FeaturePhone") {
    render(view: '/featurephone/expanded_search')
    }
}
```

This is my test method:

```
void testExtendedSearchIndex01() {
    deviceServiceMock.demand.getDeviceClass(1..10) { def myRequest, boolean verbose ->
        return "FeaturePhone"
    }
    controller.deviceService = deviceServiceMock.createMock()
    controller.extendedSearchIndex()

    assert view == "/featurephone/expanded_search"
}
```

This test fails because view is null. But why is it null? Shouldn't it be `/featurephone/expanded_search`? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

– Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mocked a signature of the method `getDeviceClass()` that needs a `def` and a `boolean`, but your controller use another that needs only a `def`. I think that your mock should be:

```
deviceServiceMock.demand.getDeviceClass(1..10) { def myRequest ->
  return "FeaturePhone"
}
```

A suggestion is to use a String for deviceClass, since you know the type returned by `getDeviceClass()`:

```
String deviceClass = deviceService.getDeviceClass(request)
if(deviceClass == "FeaturePhone")
```

And if you use an IDE, e.g. STS, you can debug your controller to check the value returned by the service.

Comment: That was totally it! My problem was that the method getDeviceClass() is overloaded. I've mocked the wrong signature. Thanks a lot!